# Error: Undefined routing for create form action field - laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, routes, undefined

I want to insert data from create.blade. But it was encountered an error for undefined routing.

```
Route [Question.store] not defined. (View: ......\myapp\resources\views\questions\create.blade.php)
```

Here is my route defined

```
Route::resource('questions', 'QuestionController');
Route::resource('options', 'OptionController');
Route::resource('votes', 'VoteController');
```

QuestionControler code sample:

```
   public function create()
        {
            return view('questions.create');
        }    

   public function store(Request $request)
        {
            //             
        }
```

My **create blade form**

```
<form method="post" action="{{route('question.store')}}">
```

How to solve this. I have used **laravel 5.8**

Thanks!

Comment: dont put up pictures of code, code is text, add it to your question .... type `php artisan route:list` and see what your routes are named, you are using the wrong route name

Comment: action="/question/index" use like this

Comment: php artisan route:list helps me to find correct routes. It solves the problem. Can I know why I have to put "questions.store" instead of "question.store" where I have the "store" function in the "questionController"? @lagbox

Comment: because you defined the resource name as `questions` .. `Route::resource('questions', ...)` ... the first argument is the resource name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have defined resource route as `questions` but using it as `question`. this is causing the error. make it like below

```
<form method="post" action="{{route('questions.store')}}">
```

Answer (score 1):

use this command to list all your routes

```
php artisan route:list
```

your route would be `questions.store` instead of `question.store` (with prefix if any)

For more information read [Resource controller](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/controllers#resource-controllers)